# WPF bind boolean value to image display

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to display either a red or green icon in several grids based upon the value of a Boolean variable set by machine states(off/on).  Is the converter the best way to accomplish this?  I am having troubles binding my variables to the image field on my grid.  I cannot seem to fire off my booltoimageconverter class?
Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: I would go with a trigger

Comment: i would use flags, put some code that you are working with, will try to get the solution

Answer (score 4):

Using BoolToImageConverter. When using this code, check all resources and paths to them. (images, converters, models (for models and converters check Namespaces)).

**Demo:**
In this demo, I changed property with name **Flag**, and then BoolToImageConverter read this property and created BitmapImage.

[image]

**App.xaml:**

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:converters"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <conv:BoolToImageConverter x:Key="BoolToImageConv" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <!--Image for demonstration, with binding-->
    <Image x:Name="TargetImageBlock" Source="{Binding Flag, Converter={StaticResource BoolToImageConv}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Width="100"/>
    <!--Button for changing property in view model-->
    <Button Content="Change" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="15" Padding="15" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.cs:**

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    // create some view model
    SomeModel model = new SomeModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Loaded -= MainWindow_Loaded;
        // set context
        this.DataContext = model;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // change property in view model (not image)
        if (model.Flag)
            model.Flag = false;
        else
            model.Flag = true;
    }        
}
```

**SomeModel.cs:**

```
        public class SomeModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool _flag = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// This flag is your bool value.
    /// </summary>
    public bool Flag
    {
        get { return _flag; }
        set
        {
            if (_flag != value)
            {
                _flag = value;
                Notify();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Notify([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        var h = PropertyChanged;
        if (h != null)
            h(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

**BoolToImageConverter:**

```
    namespace converters
{
    public class BoolToImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool val = (bool)value;
            if (val)
            {
                return new BitmapImage(new Uri("/images/like.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            }
            else
            {
                return new BitmapImage(new Uri("/images/favs.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Value converters would work. Definately.

Nevertheless, I feel like all related to the program appearence should reside in xaml. This is how it was designed.

Just think what if user wants to choose colors theme for your grid? With converters you will probably need to do some hacks to get things done. But with styles it is more natural - you just write a new one and set it dynamically.

I'm about to show solution based on triggers. It sets colors, however working with images would also be the same.

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf1.MainWindow"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
   <Window.Resources>
       <Style x:Key="ColorfulTextBlock" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
           <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsGreen}" Value="True">
                   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" ></Setter>
               </DataTrigger>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsGreen}" Value="False">
                   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" ></Setter>
               </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
   </Window.Resources>
   <StackPanel>
       <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ColorfulTextBlock}">
            Color is changed when checbox is clicked
        </TextBlock>
       <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsGreen}"></CheckBox>
   </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind (just to primitively assign vm, can be done via xaml though)

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext =new MainVm();
        }
    }
```

ViewModel

```
   public sealed class MainVm : DependencyObject
    {
       public static readonly DependencyProperty IsGreenProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("IsGreen", typeof (bool), typeof (MainVm), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

       public bool IsGreen
        {
           get { return (bool) GetValue(IsGreenProperty); }
           set { SetValue(IsGreenProperty,value); }
        }
    }
```